# How can I check the ASP .NET MVC version running on a server with a .aspx file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

For example, for the .NET Version I solved with this:

```
"The .NET version is " : <%= System.Environment.Version.ToString()%>
```

But what about the ASP .NET MVC version?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
typeof(Controller).Assembly.GetName().Version
```

Comment: thank you @SLaks! However I do not think I could do that because I am working on a web form classic .aspx... I want to know which mvc version is running on the server...

Comment: @cacho: MVC doesn't run on a server.  It's just a DLL that you put in your `bin` folder.

Comment: thanks again! you are right, I have checked and the DLL is under /bin folder. But I still do not know how to get the version because it is a remote server... I want to build an .aspx so I can pass to my client and check this remotely....

Comment: You can load the assembly dynamically by calling `Assembly.Load("System.Web.Mvc")`

Comment: this finally worked for me: `<%=typeof(Controller).Assembly.CodeBase%>`, can you update your answer please and then I will mark as an accepted answer.... Thank you very much.